# Determine all possible values of $p$ and $q$ such that $A^2$ is an upper triangular matrix with det$(A^2)=81$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given a matrix, $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -2\\ 
 p& q & 0\\ 
 0&0  &p-q 
\end{pmatrix}$$ where $p$ and $q$ are constants,

Determine all possible values of $p$ and $q$ such that $A^2$ is an upper triangular matrix with det$(A^2)=81$

My attempt:
I found $$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
p+1 & q+1 & -2(p-q+1)\\ 
 0& p+q^2 & -2p\\ 
 0&0  &(p-q)^2 
\end{pmatrix}$$

But I cant find the possible values of $p$ and $q$ such that the determinant is 81.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error for $A^2$.  It should read
$$A^2 = \begin{bmatrix}p+1 & q+1 & -2(p-q+1) \\ \color{red}{p(q+1)} & p+q^2 & -2p \\ 0 & 0 & (p-q)^2 \end{bmatrix}.$$  This is perhaps why you got stuck.

Since $A^2$ must be upper triangular, this implies $p(q+1) = 0$.  Thus we have two cases:  either $p = 0$, or $q = -1$.  In either case, $\det A^2$ is the product of the entries on the main diagonal, so for the case $p = 0$, we would also require $q$ to satisfy
$$\det A^2 = (0+1)(0+q^2)(0-q)^2 = q^4 = 81.$$
Solve for all such $q$, which then gives you solutions of the form $(0,q)$.  Then, separately, do the same for the case $q = -1$, which will give you solutions of the form $(p,-1)$.